# scheme unbound identifier error in module in: symbol <?

Tags: scheme

The following line in my code is giving me an unbound identifier error.

```
((symbol<? x (car l)) #f)
```

can anybody please explain to me why i am getting this error and how I could resolve it.

Here's the whole code:

```
; tests membership in ordered list of symbols

(define (member? x l)
 (cond

   ((null? l) #f)
   ((symbol=? x (car l)) #t)
   ((symbol<? x (car l)) #f)
   (else (member? x (cdr l)))))
```

Comment: `symbol<?` does not exist in any scheme I know. You have to convert it to string.

Comment: how do i convert it to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a `symbol<?` predicate, but there *is* a `string<?` - so if we convert the symbol into a string we'll be able to perform the comparison:

```
(define (symbol<? s1 s2)
  (string<? (symbol->string s1)
            (symbol->string s2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

`symbol<?` doesn't exist in Scheme. I know it's a standard procedure in the racket language, but that is not Scheme but a similar dialect.

I think you can define it like this:

```
(define (symbol<? a b)
  (string<? (symbol->string a) 
            (symbol->string b)))
```